# R: Get pairs of ID, and get the value for a particular column of the other item in the pair

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
dat <- read.table(text="TrxID Items Quant
Trx1 A Yes
Trx1 B Maybe
Trx2 E No
Trx2 B Yes
Trx3 B Definitely
Trx3 C Yes
Trx5 F No
Trx5 D Maybe", header=T)
```

I want to group by the TrxID column and create a new column `partner_value` that is equal to the Quant value for the other member in the pair.  So, for the first two values of the above df, it would look like the following:

```
>dat
TrxID Items Quant partner_value
Trx1   A     Yes       Maybe 
Trx1   B     Maybe     Yes
```

What's the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R: you can use `rev` to reverse the order of the vector:

```
transform(dat,partner_value=ave(Quant,TrxID,FUN=rev))

  TrxID Items      Quant partner_value
1  Trx1     A        Yes         Maybe
2  Trx1     B      Maybe           Yes
3  Trx2     E         No           Yes
4  Trx2     B        Yes            No
5  Trx3     B Definitely           Yes
6  Trx3     C        Yes    Definitely
7  Trx5     F         No         Maybe
8  Trx5     D      Maybe            No
```

Comment: Returning to this to say that this won't work if there's only one value for a given ID.

Answer (score 3):

This is slightly roundabout, but you can join the data with a modified version of itself, then filter for the partnered observations. It works all in one `dplyr` pipeline, or you can break it into pieces.

What I'll be doing inline is taking a copy of the data frame with just the ID and the `Quant` column labeled as `partner_value`. If I isolated or saved this to a variable, it looks like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% select(TrxID, partner_value = Quant)
#>   TrxID partner_value
#> 1  Trx1           Yes
#> 2  Trx1         Maybe
#> 3  Trx2            No
#> 4  Trx2           Yes
#> 5  Trx3    Definitely
#> 6  Trx3           Yes
#> 7  Trx5            No
#> 8  Trx5         Maybe
```

Instead, I do this inside of my `inner_join` call, joining by ID. Then I filter it to only keep observations where `Quant` and `partner_value` are different—that is, where the observation itself is joined with its partner.

```r
dat %>%
  inner_join(dat %>% select(TrxID, partner_value = Quant), by = c("TrxID")) %>%
  filter(Quant != partner_value)
#>   TrxID Items      Quant partner_value
#> 1  Trx1     A        Yes         Maybe
#> 2  Trx1     B      Maybe           Yes
#> 3  Trx2     E         No           Yes
#> 4  Trx2     B        Yes            No
#> 5  Trx3     B Definitely           Yes
#> 6  Trx3     C        Yes    Definitely
#> 7  Trx5     F         No         Maybe
#> 8  Trx5     D      Maybe            No
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)


dat %>% 
  group_by(TrxID) %>% 
  mutate(partner_value = sum(Quant) ) %>% 
  mutate(partner_value =partner_value-Quant  )
```

So, the result is:

```
 TrxID Items Quant partner_value
  <fct> <fct> <int>         <int>
1 Trx1  A         3             1
2 Trx1  B         1             3
3 Trx2  E         3             1
4 Trx2  B         1             3
5 Trx3  B         1             4
6 Trx3  C         4             1
7 Trx5  F         5             1
8 Trx5  D         1             5
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution, but in the actual dataset Quant is a char variable, not a numeric.  Sorry for not being specific! Any thoughts to that end?  I'll update my question

Comment: @Parseltongue Is the `partner_value` a `factor` or `char`?
But, anyways, my solution gets longer, you already received a good solution by @camille. Thanks, for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This would work. `split` the variable Quant for groups by TrxID. Use `rev` to reverse the order within each group. Because `lapply` is used, we also need `unlist` at the end. All `base R`.

```
dat$partner_value <- unlist(lapply(split(dat$Quant, ceiling(seq_along(1:nrow(dat))/2)), rev))

  TrxID Items      Quant partner_value
1  Trx1     A        Yes         Maybe
2  Trx1     B      Maybe           Yes
3  Trx2     E         No           Yes
4  Trx2     B        Yes            No
5  Trx3     B Definitely           Yes
6  Trx3     C        Yes    Definitely
7  Trx5     F         No         Maybe
8  Trx5     D      Maybe            No
```

Comment: Seems simpler to group with TrxID rather than seq_along/2. Also, you can use ave instead of split lapply unlist: `dat$partner_value = with(dat, ave(Quant, TrxID, FUN = rev))`

Answer (score 1):

Building on Salmans response...

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(Quant=factor(Quant)) %>% 
  mutate(quant_factor= as.integer(dat$Quant)) %>% 
  group_by(TrxID) %>% 
  mutate(partner_value = sum(quant_factor) ) %>% 
  mutate(partner_value =partner_value-quant_factor ) %>% 
  mutate(partner_value= levels(Quant)[partner_value]) %>% 
  select(-c(quant_factor))
```

Output as below

```
  TrxID Items Quant      partner_value
  <fct> <fct> <fct>      <chr>        
1 Trx1  A     Yes        Maybe        
2 Trx1  B     Maybe      Yes          
3 Trx2  E     No         Yes          
4 Trx2  B     Yes        No           
5 Trx3  B     Definitely Yes          
6 Trx3  C     Yes        Definitely   
7 Trx5  F     No         Maybe        
8 Trx5  D     Maybe      No
```